# ckeditor adding tags while it is already there when saving

Tags: ckeditor

I have ckeditor in my email but when i save my template and open it again the html tags get added onto again.

For example:
MY original email:

```
        <font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;">Hi there<br /> dfgs </span>
    </font> <h2 style="color: blue;">   <font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;">dfsg</span></font>
</h2> <font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;">cdgfs<br /> <span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace;">dgfs</span></span></font><br />
```

When I saved this and opened it again to edit and than save it this is what i get:

```
<font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;"><font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;"><font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;">Hi there<br />
dfgs </span></font> </span></font> </span></font>
<h2 style="color: blue;">
    <font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;"><font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;"><font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;">dfsg</span></font></span></font></span></font></h2>
<font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;"><font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;"><font size="3"><span style="font-family: Arial, Sans Serif;">cdgfs<br />
<span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace;">dgfs</span></span></font></span></font></span></font><br />
```

It keeps on adding as I save it, i there a way to fix this.

Thanks

Edit:
version - 3.6.5

CKEDITOR.config.height = 600;

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in CKEDITOR 4.0.1 with [autoParagraph](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoParagraph) disabled. It also seems to be working in the last build from v3 branch. So...

1. What version of CKE are you using? This is like fortune telling.
2. Also post your config and the way you run your editor.

Comment: Hi, I am using version 3.6.5